# .htaccess is only half working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have just created a website with html and I am trying to get the urls to look like this: www.domainname.com/hello   instead of www.domainname.com/hello.html

I found a generator called friendlyurls but only the homepage redirect will work which forces www.domainname.com instead of just domainname.com

I have tried to modify the code but had no luck can anybody shed some light on this?

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
# Force search engines to use www.domain.co.uk 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.co\.uk$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
# Specify search friendly URLs
RewriteRule ^/packages$ /packages.html [L]
```

Comment: RewriteRule ^/packages$ should be RewriteRule ^packages$ (all paths from root).

Answer (score 0):

You can use these rules in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

# Force search engines to use www.domain.co.uk 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.co\.uk$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

# To externally redirect /dir/file.html to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=302,L,NE]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```